# Save model instance in a variable before save by using deepcopy in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a `viewset` where there is a `partial_update` method that updates the values of a model instance. What I would like to do is to save the old model instance in a variable and then save the model instance with the new values so that I can compare some values after the new values are saved in database.

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        oldObj=self.get_object()

        if self.check_update_permission(request, oldObj):
            responseObject = super(ModelViewSet, self).partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
            newObj = self.get_object()

            m2mArgs = {"ModelObject": newObj, "details": request.data}
            oldObject = Model.objects.get(id = oldObj.id)
            newObj = self.saveMappedFields(**m2mArgs)
            serializer = self.readSerializer(newObj)
            responseObject.data = serializer.data
            return responseObject
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)


    def saveMappedFields(self, **args):
        modelObject = args.get("modelObject", None)
        details = args.get("details", None)
        if modelObject and details:
            # flag = False
            modelObject.model_attribute.clear()
            if "model_attribute[]" in details:
                modelObject.model_attribute.set(details.getlist("model_attribute[]"))

        return modelObject
```

What I would like is to have the value of `oldObject` value to be the old model instance values. But it is showing the values of `newObj`. How can I rectify this error?

**Edit**

I used `deepcopy` as below but even then the `oldObject` is getting updated to the values of `newObj`

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        oldObj=self.get_object()
        oldObject = copy.deepcopy(oldObj) #Here although I use deepcopy the values are still getting updated
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `oldObj.pk = None` ?

Comment: Yes. But I am getting this error. Maybe this is because the `model_attribute` is a `ManyToManyField` - `*** ValueError: "<Model: model_name>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

Comment: I get the above error if I do - `oldObject.model_attribute.all()`

Comment: Ahh, yes manytomany is a different problem.  I would try getting a value list of the related ids, and comparing those with the new list.

Comment: Yeah. I did the same thing now. Took a list of related ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to check for changes in specific fields on a model have a look at this library [django model utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker). It has a nice `FieldTracker` that you can use to track the changes in an instance and add some logic when that happens.

Otherwise, if you just want to have a history of changes just use an audit library, there are a lot of packages to use from [django packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/) depending on your needs.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Actually the problem was because the model_attribute was a `ManyToMany` field. Otherwise `deepcopy` would work fine I guess. That is to just store the model instance in a variable without saving it in database.